# How to get specific data from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking to retrieve specific data from an array such as

```
$array[] = "test type: human; Including all the test; number of participants 2 persons + additional  $50";
```

I am considering only the information of the following type:

output:

```
array[1] test type: human; 
array[2] 2
```

I should able to display only these information in the output. Test type will be varying for each case and participants number will be different for other orders.
I would like to get only the above basic information from the given array. I looked into exploding the given array by semi colon and later using the sub string to get the desired result. But looking for any efficient way to retrieve the data.
Any help or suggestions is truly appreciated.

Comment: That's not an array. it's a string. Unless you can guarantee a certain format for that string, there's no practical way to parse EVERY possible string for this information.

Comment: Your edited version is also not an array.

Comment: Every content remain in the same format and only the test type and participants keeps om changing.

Comment: Then surely there's a better way of collecting/inserting your data, if the string is changing.

Comment: Like this is just an example. If i retrieve the information from the database it will be in this format.

Comment: ...so it's a string, not an array, right?

Comment: yeah we may consider in that way

Comment: it's not a case of considering it that way, that's what it IS :). Read my answer below. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Surya, Mind telling us how your data is stored in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two possible ways to get to your result for sure there are many others but its not the easyest.

if your STRING never changes you can use option 2, else option 1

```
<?php

$array[] = "test type: human; Including all the test; number of participants 2 persons + additional  $50";

// option 1
if (preg_match_all('#test type:(.*);#Usi', $array[0], $a)) {
    echo 'test type --> '.trim(implode($a[1]));
}

if (preg_match_all('#participants(.*)persons#Usi', $array[0], $a)) {
    echo '<br />participants --> '.trim(implode($a[1]));
}
// end option 1    

    //just to show string as real array
    $arr = explode(' ', $array[0]);
    echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($arr);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '<br /><br /><br />';
    // end show

//option 2 , only works if the array, see var_dump from above is always like that
echo 'test type --> '.substr($arr[2], 0, -1);
echo '<br />participants --> '.$arr[10];
// end option 2

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You seem to misunderstand array versus string.

Array
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

String (in variable)
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

You can use the variable and string approach you currently have, but in honesty you're setting yourself up for a world of pain by having what is affectively different keys and values in single variable/string. This is what arrays are for!

A string is a single entity, maybe many chars or words etc, but should be used when you want one thing. $TheName = "Bob";
An array is when you want to store, manipulate and make use of several strings or data sets in one go. ie a load of database results.

As such, it seems to me you need to use an array. For your code to be an array, you would do something such as:

```
$array = array(
               "test type" => "human", 
               "number of participants" => "2 persons", 
                "additional" => "$50"
               );
```

The KEY of the array is the first text in "", then you assign a VALUE to that KEY by using `=>`, then the next text in quotes is the VALUE. You separate each KEY and VALUE pair with a comma, the final KEY and VALUE pair in the array does not need a comma.

This above is created manually, however you can create this in a loop from a database query. Replacing the manually assigned KEY names as above with perhaps the database column name, and the VALUE would likely be the field's data.

As for your question "get specific data from array", you would then loop the array, echoing or assigning each KEY's VALUE to a variable.
eg

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  {
    echo "The ."$key." is ".$value;
  }
```

You really need to read some tutorials on the basics. This is a Q&A site and while we'll help you with questions you have, you do need to understand the basics of what you're coding before you can ask a question about it.
As with above, the answer then is not an answer to a question but a guide or tutorial that can already be found on Stack Exchange sites, forums and tutorials :)

Comment: The content which i gave above in the array is from my database comment field.

Comment: But it is not valid PHP code.

Comment: @Surya - the content you gave above is NOT and array! If the text in your `$array[]` is all from a single database field, then it's designed to be one entity and can just be used like it currently is - echoed etc. If each part of that string is separate, then you should have separate columns in your db table to manage it. Or, you're stuck with a headache trying to split out potentially dynamic text from a single string.

Comment: I had figured it out. Thanks for your help. Thanks@James

Answer (score 2):

You  misunderstand the difference between [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP. Distinguishing between the two is **critical**. I'll assume your data is in string format.

String manipulation to the rescue! If there's no identifiable pattern or format to your data, extracting the desired information will be difficult. If your string *always* begins with `test type:` and the value following it *always* ends with a semicolon, you might do something as follows (not ideal, but it's simple):

```
$str = 'test type: human; Including all the test; number of participants 2 persons + additional  $50';
$testType = substr($str, 11, strpos($str, ';')-11); // 11 == len('test type: ')
```

Similarly, if your string always contains the text `number of participants` immediately before the desired data, and if there is a space immediately after that data, you might use:

```
$start = strpos($str, 'number of participants') + 23;
$numPart = substr($str, $start, strpos($str, ' ', $start+1) - $start);
```

I hardcoded the indices for brevity, but they're easily replaced with string search functions (especially regex).

Resources:

- [String Functions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)
- [`substr` (substring)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)
- [`strpos` (basic search)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Granted, it answers and uses the OP's current code (so no downvote), but isn't this crying out for an `array()`?

Comment: How so? His question is related to string manipulation, not array syntax. Would you prefer to instead split the string into an array and lose the ability to perform search operations on it?

Comment: Their question is about arrays. The title and first sentence is asking about arrays. "I am looking for retrieving specific data from an array". The code looks like it should be handled with an array, not regex on what is likely to be different text each DB query. The fact they misunderstand what an array is and so used a variable/string doesn't therefore define the question :)

Comment: "I want only the information test type: human; and the value 2 in participants." He is not specifically asking about arrays, but data.  Picking apart the words of a beginner's question is rarely of any use to the beginner. It's quite clear the data is in string format. To assume otherwise makes no sense.

Comment: I wont continue to debate as spoils a question, lastly, the OP used `$array[]`, he asked about "array" in title and first sentence. But as their `$array[]` is a string I agree, it is debatable either way whether he wants an array or string. As their confusion has mixed the two together making it impossible to determine what he wants, it's not a clear cut question, the answer can be either (both mine and yours is arguably right) but as it's dubious I proposed they should consider using an array, rather than fiddling with regex etc to get changing data from a string.

Comment: He's *parsing* data, not making a design decision about *how* to store it. You're 110% correct to encourage key-value design and improved DB schema, but his data already exists as a *string* which is what we must work with. If you've ever interacted with a database in PHP, you'll remember that queries *always* return arrays with values already mapped to column names. Regardless, I think he has more than enough information to piece together a solution.

Comment: I am sorry for the way i had written my question. I used array[] for an example. All the content which i had given in Array[]="" is what i get when i query my database. The participants and test type will vary for different records and sometimes i may have some other additional information too.

Comment: The database is returning a character array (which is the equivalent of a string). However, a character array in PHP is quite different from a PHP string, which is what caused the confusion. Consequently, your database will return a string in *PHP* and not a character array.

Comment: @CollinJSimpson Could you please vote up for the question please. As i  need to repair my existing post in order to come up against the ban.

Answer (score 1):

Why not split the data up into it's individual chunks and put it in a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
$array[] = explode('; ', "test type: human; Including all the test; number of participants 2 persons + additional  $50");
```

This would give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => test type: human
            [1] => Including all the test
            [2] => number of participants 2 persons + additional  $50
        )

)
```

If each section of the initial string had a key and a colon (i.e. 'key: some details') it would make it even easier to work with, like this:

```
$initial_data = explode('; ', "test type: human; Including: all the test; number of participants: 2 persons + additional  $50");
$clean_up = array();
foreach ($initial_data as $data) {
  $clean = explode(': ', $data);
  $clean_up[$clean[0]] = $clean[1];
}
$array[] = $clean_up;
```

This would make your array look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test type] => human
            [Including] => all the test
            [number of participants] => 2 persons + additional  $50
        )

)
```